# Matplotlib 1.0.1 to 1.4.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am fairly new to Python, and I am trying to debug a code that uses both TKinter and MatPlotLib. Initially, I was using Python 2.6.2 with MatPlotLib 1.0.1. I recently updated to Python 2.7 with MatPlotLib 1.4.2... quite a jump, a bumpy one.

Here is the code I have, it is part of a graphic interface in which is shown a graph that is updated based on parameters given by the user:

```
## -- Algorithm is over, graph the results:
self.graph = Figure()
self.curve = self.graph.add_subplot(111, animated = TRUE, aspect = self.aspectRatio)
self.curve.set_title(translate['my figure'])
self.curve.set_xlabel(translate['xlabel'])
self.curve.set_ylabel(translate['ylabel'])
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.graph, master = self.leftFrame)
self.canvas.show()
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(pady=15)
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self.leftFrame )    
self.toolbar.update()                                   
self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack()
self.inputBox[1][1].focus_set()
```

**After updating to Python 2.7 I basically see nothing in the graphic interface anymore, there is no graph plotted**. What surprises me is that there is absolutely no error message.

Thus I am thinking there might have been some modification in the way to actually plot or show a graph from MatPlotLib 1.0.1 to 1.4.2. Is there something obvious that I am missing here ? Could anyone have an idea about what may have changed in MatPlotLib that could create this issue ?

I wish I could be more specific, but **the absence of error message** makes it extremely hard to debug...

---

I kept invetigating this issue and found out that the problem appears going from **MatPlotLib 1.0.1** to **MatPlotLib 1.1.1** which narrows down my scan of the release notes ([MatPlotLib, what is new in 1.1](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#new-in-matplotlib-1-1)) in order to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have "animated" set as true and you are not actually doing an animation (at least not from what you have shown).  Change

```
self.curve = self.graph.add_subplot(111, animated = TRUE, aspect = self.aspectRatio)
```

to

```
self.curve = self.graph.add_subplot(111, aspect = self.aspectRatio)
```

If you want to do an animation [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/old_animation/animation_blit_qt4.html) is an example.

Comment: Thank you ! It works indeed ! So I am assuming the issue was this "misuse" of "animated = TRUE" was accepted in 1.0.1 but not in newer releases...

Comment: I do not know why it worked in 1.0.1, but it need not be used if you have no interest in animating.